# SQLITE3 Mistaking a WHERE statement for a Column Name

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm having an issue with updating `sqlite3` rows in a python loop. I'm trying to loop through every row, and update a particular column.

However, I'm getting this error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: row[0] (value of it)
```

from this query `...'where currency_name = ' + row[0]` in my code.

I think it's a syntax thing I'm doing wrong? I've tried splitting it up into sub-statements, but that hasn't worked either. My code is below.

```
import sqlite3
import requests

conn = sqlite3.connect('cryptoindex-holdings.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

for row in conn.execute('SELECT * FROM currency'):
    r = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/' + row[0] + '/?convert=CAD')
    r = r.json()

    market_cap = r[0]['market_cap_cad']
    sql = "UPDATE currency SET market_cap = " + market_cap + " WHERE currency_name = " + row[0]

    cursor.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
```

and my DB Schema is:

```
currency (
    currency_name TEXT,
    market_cap REAL,
    coin_price REAL,
    coins_owned REAL
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not string escaping the the value in your `WHERE` statement. Your code happens to work for the other values because they are of type `REAL`. However, when you compare with the `currency_name` column (type `TEXT`), it breaks.

This occurs because it thinks your string value (`row[0]`) is actually a column. To force it to recognize it as a string, change this line:

```
sql = "UPDATE currency SET market_cap = " + market_cap + " WHERE   currency_name=" + row[0]
```

to

```
sql = "UPDATE currency SET market_cap = {} WHERE currency_name = '{}'".format(market_cap, row[0])
```

Now the `currency_name` value is string escaped, and will be correctly recognized.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. Now I know to read about string escaping :)